# How do I make sense of different proof-methods in symbolic logic?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, modal-logic

I don't know if this is the right place for this question, so if it isn't let me know.

So I initially learned symbolic logic from Introducing Symbolic Logic by Robert Martain where we learned to do proofs using a certain set of rules. After the course, I started to look into modal logic in A New Introduction to Modal Logic by Hughes and Cresswell, but there they used axioms rather than rules for proofs. Are these two distinct methods, or are they reducible to each other? Like, can you take any set of axioms and turn them into rules, and vice versa? And if they are distinct, I am confused on how two distinct methods of proof can be invented and guaranteed to be valid.

Comment: There are many proof systems: Axioms+rules [aka: Hilbert-style], Natural Deduction, Sequent Calculus, Truth Tree, Resolution. All are sound and complete for the corresponding "semantics": classical, intuitionistic, modal.

Comment: Oh wow. I see there is a lot I don't know. Is there any book you know of that can teach me more about these methods?

Comment: Ben-Ari, [Mathematical Logic](http://202.88.229.59:8080/xmlui/bitstream/handle/123456789/1058/Mathematical%20Logic%20for%20Computer%20Science%20%20Mordechai%20Ben-Ari.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y)

Comment: You could was well read some basic stuff on proof systems and proof theory. For an accessible introduction to some proof systems see David Bostock's 'Intermediate Logic'. There, Hilbert systems, trees, natural deduction and sequent systems are covered to some length.  There is also a nice intro text by Jan von Plato, namely his 'Elements of Logical Reasoning',  where basic aspects of classical logic are presented from the viewpoint of sequent systems and natural deduction systems.